# The probabilities of something happening

Tags: probability, contest-math

> In the case of event $A$, which has a $40\%$ chance of happening, there is a $60\%$ chance to score a point. If event $A$ does not happen, event $B$ would have a $60\%$ chance of happening which would result in a $39\%$ chance to score a point. If neither events happen the chances of scoring a point are $30\%$. What are the chances of scoring a point?

So far I have tried $0.4\times0.6+0.6\times0.6\times0.39+0.6\times0.4\times0.3$  which would give you $0.4524$ which would be about $45\%$ but I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @James Your answer looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [the law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) twice for this.

With event $S$ as the event a point is scored, and $'$ indicating the complement of an event:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(S) = \mathbb P(S|A)\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P (S|A')\mathbb P(A') \quad \text{&} \quad \\ \mathbb P (S|A') = \mathbb P (S|B, A')\mathbb P(B|A')  + \mathbb P (S|B', A')\mathbb P(B'|A') \\ 
\implies \mathbb P(S) = \mathbb P(S|A)\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P (S|B, A')\mathbb P(B|A')\mathbb P(A')  + \mathbb P (S|B', A')\mathbb P(B'|A')\mathbb P(A') \\
= .6 \cdot .4 + .39 \cdot .6 \cdot .6 + .3 \cdot.4 \cdot .6 \\
= 0.4524
\end{align}